# unable access to kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I cannot access to kibana even that it is running on the same server with elasticsearch, I've got the following message from Kibana url, https://localhost:5601:

```
statusCode  401
error   "Unauthorized"
message "[missing authentication credentials for REST request [/.kibana_7.17.6/_search?from=0&rest_total_hits_as_int=true&size=1000]: security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/.kibana_7.17.6/_search?from=0&rest_total_hits_as_int=true&size=1000]]: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/.kibana_7.17.6/_search?from=0&rest_total_hits_as_int=true&size=1000]"
```

kibana yml :

```
server.host: 0.0.0.0
server.port: 5601
elasticsearch.hosts: localhost:9200
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: TNrVNnxqlaam45iJJzgz
# Elasticsearch from/to Kibana 
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: /etc/kibana/certs/ca/ca.crt
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.crt 
elasticsearch.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.key
# Browser from/to Kibana server.ssl.enabled: true 
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.crt 
server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.key 
 Elasticsearch authentication
xpack.security.enabled: false
elasticsearch.username: elastic 
uiSettings.overrides.defaultRoute: "/app/wazuh" 
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate 
telemetry.banner: false
```

elasticsearch yml :

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.name: elasticsearch
cluster.initial_master_nodes: elasticsearch
# Transport layer
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt



HTTP layer xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true 
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key 
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt 
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt
# Elasticsearch authentication 
xpack.security.enabled: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share kibana.yml and elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: this is kibana yml : server.host: 0.0.0.0
server.port: 5601
elasticsearch.hosts: https://localhost:9200
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: TNrVNnxqlaam45iJJzgz
# Elasticsearch from/to Kibana
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: /etc/kibana/certs/ca/ca.crt
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.crt
elasticsearch.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.key
# Browser from/to Kibana
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.crt
server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.key

Comment: also kibana yml : 
# Elasticsearch authentication
xpack.security.enabled: false
elasticsearch.username: elastic
uiSettings.overrides.defaultRoute: "/app/wazuh"
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate
telemetry.banner: false

Comment: and this is elasticsearch yml : network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.name: elasticsearch
cluster.initial_master_nodes: elasticsearch

# Transport layer
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt

Comment: also elasticsearch yml : 
# HTTP layer
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt

# Elasticsearch authentication
xpack.security.enabled: true  
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for sharing but please edit the question and add the information into there. It's hard to read like that

Comment: okkey i willl do it  , thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing, next time please make sure you shared with appropriate format.
To diagnose the issue can send the following API call and share the results in the question?

`curl -k "https://localhost:9200" -u elastic:TNrVNnxqlaam45iJJzgz`